# How do you do maths (or math) with numbers bigger than MaxValue in C#?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Big integers in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176775/big-integers-in-c-sharp)

I want to be able to process arbitrarily large numbers in C#.
I can live with just integers.

Are there established algorithms for this kind of thing?
Or is there a good 3rd-party library?

I might consider changing language if there really is no good way to do it in C#.

Thanks for any help / suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check the [Big Num](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) kind of libraries. In C# the most popular ones are: [IntX](http://www.codeplex.com/IntX/) and [W3b.Sine](http://www.codeplex.com/sine), plus, they are both Open Source.

Comment: Thanks for the links, havent seen those 2 before :)  Maybe they will be faster than the rubbish in the DLR!

Answer (score 3):

Someone has done a BigInteger class in C# at codeproject
[C# BigInteger Class](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/biginteger.aspx).
Worth checking out.

And a sample of the general algorithm can be found at : [Re: Hi-prec math for visual studio c#?](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=246407) (It's the post at the bottom of the page with the code snippet)

Answer (score 2):

As people have mentioned, there are various 3rd-party implementations of a BigInteger class. Also, C# 4.0 will be getting a native BigInteger class in the CLR.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need very large numbers, you could use `long` (64-bit), or even `decimal` (128-bit floating point).

If you need values larger than 9223372036854775807 (`long`) or 79228162514264337593543950335 (`decimal`), then you need to ignore this answer.