# How do I multiply two large numbers stored as strings in the C#?

Tags: c#, algorithm

i want to ask how i am able to multiply large numbers in C#.
If i had

```
string firstNumber = 135923852358239582395823952382395823951825873295723957623875623857263587236589273567283562835726385723656827356235235;

string secondNumber= 135923852358239582395823952382395823951825873295723957623875623857263587236589273567283562835726385723656827356235235;
```

i want to do this 
firstNumber * Second Number

Comment: You could parse them into [`BigInteger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx).  `Console.WriteLine(BigInteger.Parse(firstNumber) * BigInteger.Parse(secondNumber));`

Comment: btw you missed double quotes for strings.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/279038/447156

Comment: You don't.  Those number are bigger then big integer.  Why would you need to multiply number that big?

Comment: @Paparazzi No they're not.  The answer (via parsing to BigInteger) is 18475293639904512084559159038493973411283439804954005546376625603615812799023790492467237643300612205082402966970756925004844150484699383955740178979751400427519750333764207395320715014879702523078179084504091642998778302232655505225

Comment: @juharr Correct, I was looking at Uint64