# I need big numeric variable in C#

Tags: c#, variables, integer

I need to save power 1024 of 2 in a variable in c#
what should i do?
i tried this :

```
label1.Text = "0";
decimal res = 0;
res += System.Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Pow(2, 1024));
label1.Text = System.Convert.ToString(res);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [working with incredibly large numbers in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279038/working-with-incredibly-large-numbers-in-net)

Comment: Use a BigInteger - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That's a gigantic number. It's going to have more than 300 digits. I hope your label is really long.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use a [**BigInteger**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var exponentiated = BigInteger.Pow(2, 1024);
var newText = exponentiated.ToString();
```

Also, if you are using an environment where the .Net `BigInteger` class is not available (a project targeting .Net version 2 for example), you can use an external implementation like any of these:

- [BigInt on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36323/BigInt)
- [BigInteger on CodePlex](http://biginteger.codeplex.com/)
- [C# BigInteger Class on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2728/C-BigInteger-Class)
- [Bouncy Castle's BigInteger on Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/BigInteger.cs)
- [Mono's BigInteger on GitHub](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Math/BigInteger.cs)
- [Mpir.NET big integers on GitHub](https://github.com/wezeku/Mpir.NET)
- [IntX on GitHub](https://github.com/devoyster/IntXLib)