# What should I use for a BigInt class in .NET?

Tags: .net, biginteger

Until BCL finally ships [System.Numeric.BigInt](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2008/01/04/where-did-biginteger-go-melitta-andersen.aspx), what do you guys use for arbitrary precision integers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try mine on codeplex: [BigInteger](http://www.codeplex.com/biginteger)

Or here's another: [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/biginteger.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

F# has `Microsoft.FSharp.Math.BigInt` and `Microsoft.FSharp.Math.BigNum`.

Comment: What's the difference, do you know?

Comment: From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee620695.aspx): "This type is provided for use only with the F# Core Library Versions that targets .NET Framework 2.0. If you are using .NET Framework 4, use the .NET Framework 4 type with the same name, BigInteger."

Comment: Thanks, but I was asking what's the difference between FSharp.BigInt and BigNum.

Comment: @nawfal I think they're both obsolete, but for information: `BigInt`: integers, `BigNum`: rationals.

Comment: Ok I get it. Should have been obvious for me from the name! :)

Answer (score 3):

Also, the [J# library includes a BigInt type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176775/big-integers-in-c).

Thankfully, all this will be sorted out when the BCL finally ships a standardized BigInt.

***UPDATE 2012*** [System.Numberics.BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) is now included in the .NET framework.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

[IronRuby.StandardLibrary.BigDecimal.BigDecimal](http://www.ironruby.net/)

Comment: Is it available as a simple DLL I can reference? (I'm coding in C# if that matters).

Comment: It's MPL so you should be free to reuse the file

Comment: I wasn't asking about the license terms, just about the ease of use.

Comment: It looks like it would be fairly simple to extract this from iron ruby