# how to represent large numbers in C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I use for a BigInt class in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567753/what-should-i-use-for-a-bigint-class-in-net)

I need to represent large numbers in C#.

I tried `Int64`, but now I need to deal with 68! (factorial(68)).

I checked `UInt64` and it also isn't good enough.

people here say to use BigInteger, but I understand that .NET 3.5 doesn't support it by some reason.. so what should I do?

Answer (score 4):

Use [System.Numerics.BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx).

Comment: I understand that .NET 3.5 doesn't support it by some reason..                     so what should I do?

Comment: @George add that to your question and then see the responses on the question Adam Sills left in his comment

Answer (score 2):

Would `System.Numerics.BigInteger` be appropriate?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx

Answer (score 1):

`BigInteger` can hold almost any integer value.But you should remember the following :

> "Because the BigInteger type is immutable (see Mutability and the
>   BigInteger Structure) and because it has no upper or lower bounds, an
>   OutOfMemoryException can be thrown for any operation that causes a
>   BigInteger value to grow too large."