# how to make Int1024

Tags: c#, .net, biginteger, infrastructure

how to declare int1024 in C#? i can use VB or C++ Too.

Regards
Behrooz

Comment: Are you asking how to declare a 1,024-bit integer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See this question: [Big integers in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176775/big-integers-in-c)

From the answer to that question:

> MS is going to introduce System.Numerics.BigInteger class in .NET 4.0
>
> Until then, look at [IntX](http://www.codeplex.com/IntX/) class.
>
> > IntX is an arbitrary precision integers library written in pure C# 2.0 with fast - O(N * log N) - multiplication/division algorithms implementation. It provides all the basic operations on integers like addition, multiplication, comparing, bitwise shifting etc.

Answer (score 4):

And by that do you mean a 1024-bit integer? Better wait until [`BigInteger` in 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(VS.100).aspx). Until then, the cheekiest you can do with the *core* libraries is to (ab)use `decimal`, which has 96 bits for the integer part. Or use a 3rd-party dll.

Answer (score 3):

Just for avoidance of doubt:

```
public int int1024 = 1024;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want a 1024 bit integer.

Unfortunately there is no inbuilt 1024 bit integer type in .net. You would have to find a specialised library for that kind of thing or write one yourself.

There is an article about big integers [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/biginteger.aspx?df=100&forumid=4524&exp=0&fr=26).