# Is there a "Number" struct/class in .NET?

Tags: .net, numbers, base-class-library

I am attempting to store a ***variable length*** number that can have leading zeros as a part of that number.

Is there a class in the .NET framework capable of storing values like this ***without losing information about leading zeros***, and could ***surpass the upper limit of a long***?

I am currently storing them in a class like this, is there any way I could write this class better in the event there isn't some struct or class available in the BCL:

```
[Serializable]
public class Number
{
    public int[] Array { get; set; }
    public int Length { get { return Array.Length; } }

    public Number(string number)
    {
        Array = new int[number.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < number.Length; i++)
        {
            Array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(number[i].ToString());
        }
    }

    public Number(int[] array)
    {
        Array = array;
    }

    public int ToInt()
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(ToString());
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(Array.Length);

        foreach (int i in Array)
            sb.Append(i);

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

The ability to use this as a struct would be very useful, as would the ability to check equality easily.

Items in bold/italic are the requirements of such a class.

Comment: Aren't you wanting a string? I see no number operations...

Comment: If you really want something that can exceed the upper limit of the `long` type, you're going to need to rethink your `ToInt` method.

Comment: Essentially yes, however I wanted to enforce at the class/struct level the inability to use non-numeric data, and to make it clear wherever it is used in code that this was the intention.

Comment: Good point Dan, however that was added to support some values that were stored as strings, and converted to int. Messy way of doing things definitely. +1 for pointing that out, need to add a comment warning about that in the code.

Comment: Why do you need the leading digits? What kind of "number" is this? I say "number" in quotes, because it sounds to me like what you're really storing is a code, like a SSN or zip-code or whatever, not actually a number. That it happens to only be allowed to have digits doesn't make it any less of a code. The normal way to store codes is through strings.

Comment: It's not what you're looking for, but there is an internal class in the `System` namespace called `Number`.  It throws `FormatException`'s on certain bad WCF service calls.  I mention it in case someone else searches `.NET Number class` and ends up here. http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Number@cs/1305376/Number@cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest taking a look at this [question about big integers in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176775/big-integers-in-c). You could expand them for the leading zeros issue.

Comment: Thank you! Can definitely use that since need to rely on 3.5 for time being, and can add the code to handle leading zeros myself.

Answer (score 2):

I see a number of problems with your class that should be addressed with the redesign.

- Your class represents a value and is mutable.
- The constructor taking an int array parameter only copies the reference.
- The value can be larger than long but is returned as an int from the ToInt() method.

The first thing I would do to shrink the size of this class is use the array of integers as a constant stream of bits which make up a binary representation of your number.  This would take a lot more care in order to ensure correctness of any desired operations, but would save you a significant amount of space.  If you do that, I would also store a variable to keep track of leading 0's, or perhaps a variable "total digits" semantics.

Sorry this isn't an answer to your question, but hopefully it will help you in redesigning this your class.

Answer (score 0):

The [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(VS.100).aspx) in .Net 4.0 addresses your upper limit requirement.

I think you'd still need a class like this to handle your leading zeros requirement.

Comment: I did notice that when searching to see if Int128 had been implemented in .NET yet when someone posted (then deleted) their comment about using long long. I suppose I could create a struct in .NET 4.0 to hold the BigNumber and a "length" value to determine what leading zeros are needed when padding.

Answer (score 0):

Until [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(VS.100).aspx) is openly available, I would create your own class/struct with one public string property to get/set the initial number (this will maintain your leading zeros).  Then have a ReadOnly property that parses the string and returns an [IntX](http://www.codeplex.com/IntX/) instance.