# C#: How Should I Handle Arithmetic with Huge Numbers?

Tags: c#, .net, string, biginteger

I'm writing an app which involves arithmetic with humongous numbers, with very many digits. I've previously written a class that simplifies handling big numbers by defining them as strings and then using slow arithmetic string functions. Is this the best way to do it? If not, how should I approach this problem? Does C# have anything built-in for such situations?

Comment: Int64 won't suffice? Could you give an example of an arithmetic action you'd like to perform?

Comment: Will System.Decimal be large enough for you? The largest value that can be represented with it is 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335.

Comment: "Humongous" is not actually a useful description. Are we talking about numbers with twenty digits, a thousand digits, a million digits, a billion digits or more than a billion digits?  The answer to your question will be different for each.

Comment: How about a few hundred digits?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.NET 4 will have this built in via the BigInteger type.  This is claimed to be pretty well tuned and should perform very well.

For 3.5 and earlier, you can grab an implementation of BigInteger from the [Dynamic Language Runtime](http://www.codeplex.com/dlr) sources.  (See e.g. http://dlr.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/changeset/view/40021?projectName=dlr#694008 and drill down into Src / Runtime / Microsoft.Dynamic / Math.)  I don't know if this has been tuned as highly as the .NET 4 BigInteger type, but it should still be more efficient than your string version because it internally represents the big numbers using integral types and performs arithmetic using integer operations.

Answer (score 7):

If you can do it on .NET 4, [System.Numeric.BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger_members(VS.100).aspx) can help. If you're on an older version of .NET, [IntX](http://www.codeplex.com/IntX/) will help you.

See also this [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176775/big-integers-in-c) on big integers in C#.

Answer (score 1):

The GNU MP bignum library is one of the fastest around. there's a .NET wrapper for it
http://gnumpnet.codeplex.com/

Here's another [bignum library](http://porg.es/blog/a-simple-bignum-library-for-dot-net) for .NET with source.

Answer (score 1):

Big Integer class that I've used many times for cryptography projects (where extremely large numbers are needed). Works great.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/biginteger.aspx

Answer (score -1):

In dotnet version above 4.0, 
`System.Numerics.BigInteger` will help you for this problem.

if you get assembly reference error using the above syntax, then add reference using

http://www.dllme.com/dll/files/system_numerics_dll.html.

Hope this will help you..!