# Base-N encoding of a byte array

Tags: c#, algorithm, encoding, bit-manipulation, radix

A couple of days ago I came across [this CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14084/base-36-encoding-of-a-byte-array/) for Base-36 encoding a byte array. However, the answers that followed didn't touch on decoding back into a byte array, or possibly reusing the answer to perform encodings of different bases (radix).

The answer for the linked question uses BigInteger. So as far as implementation goes, the base and its digits could be parametrized.

The problem with BigInteger though, is that we're treating our input as an assumed integer. However, our input, a byte array, is just an opaque series of values.

- If the byte array ends in a series of zero bytes, eg {0xFF,0x7F,0x00,0x00}, those bytes will be lost when using the algorithm in the answer (would only encode {0xFF,0x7F}.
- If the last non-zero byte has the sign bit set then the proceeding zero byte is consumed as it's treated as the BigInt's sign delimiter. So {0xFF,0xFF,0x00,0x00} would encode only as {0xFF,0xFF,0x00}.

*How could a .NET programmer use BigInteger to create a reasonably efficient and radix-agnostic encoder, with decoding support, plus the ability to handle endian-ness, and with the ability to 'work around' the ending zero bytes being lost?*

Comment: The last one is easy to target.

Comment: Sorry, this was suppose to be an self Q&A question but I had to spend the last 8 minutes or so figuring out where the answer form thought I had non-proper code lines. All while the question was posted. Shouldn't self Q&A posts halt the question posting until the answer is good too? Anyway, answer is now posted.

Comment: Not reversible with this input: `byte[] test = new byte[] {18, 231, 34, 57, 58, 64, 96, 49, 196, 21, 50, 161, 207, 202, 244, 119, 160, 52, 33, 201, 201, 164, 24, 106, 84, 44, 71, 94, 15, 209, 235, 177};`

Comment: Refer to the "edit2" part of this post for the reason why http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/20014/20654. If you pad your byte array with an additional "0" byte, it will work. Sadly, there's no BigInteger byte[] ctor which allows you to tell it to assume the bytes lead to an 'unsigned' value. The only real way to get around this is to check the sign bit of the last byte and if set, Array.Resize() the input by one (which will implicitly add a zero byte).

Comment: If you're still interested in this and it doesn't have to be universally mathematically portable, I'd suggest considering chunking. I've implemented the numeric div/mod work on uint64 arithmetic, converting 8 bytes at a time (produces 11 chars for base62, would need 10.75 chars, 2.3% overhead). Not as space-efficient, but almost, and way faster (have no comparison but there's no slow arbitrary-length integer involved).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**edit** [2020/01/26]: FWIW, the [code below](https://github.com/KornnerStudios/KSoft/blob/master/KSoft/Text/RadixEncoding.cs) along with its [unit test](https://github.com/KornnerStudios/KSoft/blob/master/Test.KSoft.BCL/Text/RadixEncodingTest.cs) live along side my [open source libraries on Github](https://github.com/KornnerStudios/Vita).

**edit** [2016/04/19]: If you're fond of exceptions, you may wish to change some of the Decode implementation code to throw `InvalidDataException` instead of just returning null.

**edit** [2014/09/14]: I've added a 'HACK' to Encode() to handle cases where the last byte in the input is signed (if you were to convert to sbyte). Only sane solution I could think of right now is to just Resize() the array by one. Additional unit tests for this case passed, but I didn't rerun perf code to account for such cases. If you can help it, always have your input to Encode() include a dummy 0 byte at the end to avoid additional allocations.

### Usage

I've created a RadixEncoding class (found in the "Code" section) which initializes with three parameters:

1. The radix digits as a string (length determines the actual radix of course),
2. The assumed byte ordering (endian) of input byte arrays,
3. And whether or not the user wants the encode/decode logic to acknowledge ending zero bytes.

To create a Base-36 encoding, with little-endian input, and with respect given to ending zero bytes:

```
const string k_base36_digits = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var base36_no_zeros = new RadixEncoding(k_base36_digits, EndianFormat.Little, false);
```

And then to actually perform encoding/decoding:

```
const string k_input = "A test 1234";
byte[] input_bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(k_input);
string encoded_string = base36_no_zeros.Encode(input_bytes);
byte[] decoded_bytes = base36_no_zeros.Decode(encoded_string);
```

### Performance

Timed with Diagnostics.Stopwatch, ran on an i7 860 @2.80GHz. Timing EXE ran by itself, not under a debugger.

Encoding was initialized with the same **k_base36_digits** string from above, EndianFormat.Little, and with **ending zero bytes acknowledged** (even though the UTF8 bytes don't have any extra ending zero bytes)

To encode the UTF8 bytes of "A test 1234" 1,000,000 times takes 2.6567905secs
To decode the same string the same amount of times takes 3.3916248secs

To encode the UTF8 bytes of "A test 1234. Made slightly larger!" 100,000 times takes 1.1577325secs
To decode the same string the same amount of times takes 1.244326secs

### Code

If you don't have a [CodeContracts generator](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/), you will have to reimplement the contracts with if/throw code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Numerics;
using Contract = System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract;

public enum EndianFormat
{
    /// <summary>Least Significant Bit order (lsb)</summary>
    /// <remarks>Right-to-Left</remarks>
    /// <see cref="BitConverter.IsLittleEndian"/>
    Little,
    /// <summary>Most Significant Bit order (msb)</summary>
    /// <remarks>Left-to-Right</remarks>
    Big,
};

/// <summary>Encodes/decodes bytes to/from a string</summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Encoded string is always in big-endian ordering
/// 
/// <p>Encode and Decode take a <b>includeProceedingZeros</b> parameter which acts as a work-around
/// for an edge case with our BigInteger implementation.
/// MSDN says BigInteger byte arrays are in LSB->MSB ordering. So a byte buffer with zeros at the 
/// end will have those zeros ignored in the resulting encoded radix string.
/// If such a loss in precision absolutely cannot occur pass true to <b>includeProceedingZeros</b>
/// and for a tiny bit of extra processing it will handle the padding of zero digits (encoding)
/// or bytes (decoding).</p>
/// <p>Note: doing this for decoding <b>may</b> add an extra byte more than what was originally 
/// given to Encode.</p>
/// </remarks>
// Based on the answers from http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14084/base-36-encoding-of-a-byte-array/
public class RadixEncoding
{
    const int kByteBitCount = 8;

    readonly string kDigits;
    readonly double kBitsPerDigit;
    readonly BigInteger kRadixBig;
    readonly EndianFormat kEndian;
    readonly bool kIncludeProceedingZeros;

    /// <summary>Numerial base of this encoding</summary>
    public int Radix { get { return kDigits.Length; } }
    /// <summary>Endian ordering of bytes input to Encode and output by Decode</summary>
    public EndianFormat Endian { get { return kEndian; } }
    /// <summary>True if we want ending zero bytes to be encoded</summary>
    public bool IncludeProceedingZeros { get { return kIncludeProceedingZeros; } }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Base-{0} {1}", Radix.ToString(), kDigits);
    }

    /// <summary>Create a radix encoder using the given characters as the digits in the radix</summary>
    /// <param name="digits">Digits to use for the radix-encoded string</param>
    /// <param name="bytesEndian">Endian ordering of bytes input to Encode and output by Decode</param>
    /// <param name="includeProceedingZeros">True if we want ending zero bytes to be encoded</param>
    public RadixEncoding(string digits,
        EndianFormat bytesEndian = EndianFormat.Little, bool includeProceedingZeros = false)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(digits != null);
        int radix = digits.Length;

        kDigits = digits;
        kBitsPerDigit = System.Math.Log(radix, 2);
        kRadixBig = new BigInteger(radix);
        kEndian = bytesEndian;
        kIncludeProceedingZeros = includeProceedingZeros;
    }

    // Number of characters needed for encoding the specified number of bytes
    int EncodingCharsCount(int bytesLength)
    {
        return (int)Math.Ceiling((bytesLength * kByteBitCount) / kBitsPerDigit);
    }
    // Number of bytes needed to decoding the specified number of characters
    int DecodingBytesCount(int charsCount)
    {
        return (int)Math.Ceiling((charsCount * kBitsPerDigit) / kByteBitCount);
    }

    /// <summary>Encode a byte array into a radix-encoded string</summary>
    /// <param name="bytes">byte array to encode</param>
    /// <returns>The bytes in encoded into a radix-encoded string</returns>
    /// <remarks>If <paramref name="bytes"/> is zero length, returns an empty string</remarks>
    public string Encode(byte[] bytes)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(bytes != null);
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>() != null);

        // Don't really have to do this, our code will build this result (empty string),
        // but why not catch the condition before doing work?
        if (bytes.Length == 0) return string.Empty;

        // if the array ends with zeros, having the capacity set to this will help us know how much
        // 'padding' we will need to add
        int result_length = EncodingCharsCount(bytes.Length);
        // List<> has a(n in-place) Reverse method. StringBuilder doesn't. That's why.
        var result = new List<char>(result_length);

        // HACK: BigInteger uses the last byte as the 'sign' byte. If that byte's MSB is set, 
        // we need to pad the input with an extra 0 (ie, make it positive)
        if ( (bytes[bytes.Length-1] & 0x80) == 0x80 )
            Array.Resize(ref bytes, bytes.Length+1);

        var dividend = new BigInteger(bytes);
        // IsZero's computation is less complex than evaluating "dividend > 0"
        // which invokes BigInteger.CompareTo(BigInteger)
        while (!dividend.IsZero)
        {
            BigInteger remainder;
            dividend = BigInteger.DivRem(dividend, kRadixBig, out remainder);
            int digit_index = System.Math.Abs((int)remainder);
            result.Add(kDigits[digit_index]);
        }

        if (kIncludeProceedingZeros)
            for (int x = result.Count; x < result.Capacity; x++)
                result.Add(kDigits[0]); // pad with the character that represents 'zero'

        // orientate the characters in big-endian ordering
        if (kEndian == EndianFormat.Little)
            result.Reverse();
        // If we didn't end up adding padding, ToArray will end up returning a TrimExcess'd array, 
        // so nothing wasted
        return new string(result.ToArray());
    }

    void DecodeImplPadResult(ref byte[] result, int padCount)
    {
        if (padCount > 0)
        {
            int new_length = result.Length + DecodingBytesCount(padCount);
            Array.Resize(ref result, new_length); // new bytes will be zero, just the way we want it
        }
    }
    #region Decode (Little Endian)
    byte[] DecodeImpl(string chars, int startIndex = 0)
    {
        var bi = new BigInteger();
        for (int x = startIndex; x < chars.Length; x++)
        {
            int i = kDigits.IndexOf(chars[x]);
            if (i < 0) return null; // invalid character
            bi *= kRadixBig;
            bi += i;
        }

        return bi.ToByteArray();
    }
    byte[] DecodeImplWithPadding(string chars)
    {
        int pad_count = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < chars.Length; x++, pad_count++)
            if (chars[x] != kDigits[0]) break;

        var result = DecodeImpl(chars, pad_count);
        DecodeImplPadResult(ref result, pad_count);

        return result;
    }
    #endregion
    #region Decode (Big Endian)
    byte[] DecodeImplReversed(string chars, int startIndex = 0)
    {
        var bi = new BigInteger();
        for (int x = (chars.Length-1)-startIndex; x >= 0; x--)
        {
            int i = kDigits.IndexOf(chars[x]);
            if (i < 0) return null; // invalid character
            bi *= kRadixBig;
            bi += i;
        }

        return bi.ToByteArray();
    }
    byte[] DecodeImplReversedWithPadding(string chars)
    {
        int pad_count = 0;
        for (int x = chars.Length - 1; x >= 0; x--, pad_count++)
            if (chars[x] != kDigits[0]) break;

        var result = DecodeImplReversed(chars, pad_count);
        DecodeImplPadResult(ref result, pad_count);

        return result;
    }
    #endregion
    /// <summary>Decode a radix-encoded string into a byte array</summary>
    /// <param name="radixChars">radix string</param>
    /// <returns>The decoded bytes, or null if an invalid character is encountered</returns>
    /// <remarks>
    /// If <paramref name="radixChars"/> is an empty string, returns a zero length array
    /// 
    /// Using <paramref name="IncludeProceedingZeros"/> has the potential to return a buffer with an
    /// additional zero byte that wasn't in the input. So a 4 byte buffer was encoded, this could end up
    /// returning a 5 byte buffer, with the extra byte being null.
    /// </remarks>
    public byte[] Decode(string radixChars)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(radixChars != null);

        if (kEndian == EndianFormat.Big)
            return kIncludeProceedingZeros ? DecodeImplReversedWithPadding(radixChars) : DecodeImplReversed(radixChars);
        else
            return kIncludeProceedingZeros ? DecodeImplWithPadding(radixChars) : DecodeImpl(radixChars);
    }
};
```

### Basic Unit Tests

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

static bool ArraysCompareN<T>(T[] input, T[] output)
    where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    if (output.Length < input.Length) return false;
    for (int x = 0; x < input.Length; x++)
        if(!output[x].Equals(input[x])) return false;

    return true;
}
static bool RadixEncodingTest(RadixEncoding encoding, byte[] bytes)
{
    string encoded = encoding.Encode(bytes);
    byte[] decoded = encoding.Decode(encoded);

    return ArraysCompareN(bytes, decoded);
}
[TestMethod]
public void TestRadixEncoding()
{
    const string k_base36_digits = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var base36 = new RadixEncoding(k_base36_digits, EndianFormat.Little, true);
    var base36_no_zeros = new RadixEncoding(k_base36_digits, EndianFormat.Little, true);

    byte[] ends_with_zero_neg = { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00 };
    byte[] ends_with_zero_pos = { 0xFF, 0x7F, 0x00, 0x00 };
    byte[] text = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("A test 1234");

    Assert.IsTrue(RadixEncodingTest(base36, ends_with_zero_neg));
    Assert.IsTrue(RadixEncodingTest(base36, ends_with_zero_pos));
    Assert.IsTrue(RadixEncodingTest(base36_no_zeros, text));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, looks really good. Is there any way to avoid the Decoder to generate an additional zero byte when using 'includeProceedingZeros'? I would really like to use your code, but I need to make sure that 'x == Decode(Encode(x))' is true for any 'x' (nothing added, nothing removed, even if it's just '0' byte).

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with the guts of this code, but if you absolutely needed this requirement, you could probably take MS's BigInteger implementation (MIT license) and change it to either take a parameter saying the BigInt is unsigned, or create a overload of ToByteArray to accomplish the same: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Runtime.Numerics/src/System/Numerics/BigInteger.cs#L269

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. Well, your code is already trying to work around the padding. I wonder, do you remember what exactly is the problem why your solution does not always work? I have found another approach to solving the padding issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7398723/298609). Do you think that solution is going to suffer from the same problem as yours?

Comment: Glancing at it, they're using BigInt too, so I'd imagine so. BigInt is little endian, meaning all proceeding zeros in a byte[] are meaningless, just like the zero in 0x00112233. However, they're not meaningless to Radix encoding, thus the work around. Then there's the additional workaround for BigInt being signed as I mentioned earlier, where an additional null byte could be introduced (what I thought you were asking about initially). More class unit tests [here](https://bitbucket.org/KornnerStudios/ksoft/src/87ce4a6e55f0cbba42d0a89c67552d012e92b854/Test.KSoft.BCL/Text/RadixEncodingTest.cs)

Comment: There's a bug. Encode `000000010AE1C70BC1A5FCCE845FECB09D7FE6FC` and decode back base-36, and you will get trailing zeroes.

Comment: It's not a bug. The last byte, 0xFC, has the most significant bit set. As discussed, BigInteger would treat that bit as the 'signed' flag. If you add an additional zero byte (ie, '...FC00') then you won't get trailing zeros. Refer to the "HACK" comment in Encode(byte[] bytes), as this is what is leading to Decode to return trailing zeros.

Comment: Rather than returning `null` when an invalid character is encountered, I think an exception should be thrown.

Comment: @RonnieOverby, users who want to pull from this code are free to use `InvalidDataException` if they wish. Coming from a C++/gamedev background, I'm picky with when/where I use exceptions, so for my use I just used null as the bad-chars sentinel.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, I was able to port Kornman's techniques across to Java and got expected output up to and including base36.  Whereas when running his? code from c# using C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 csc, the output was not as expected.

For example, trying to base16 encode the obtained MD5 hashBytes for the String "hello world" below using Kornman's RadixEncoding encode, I could see the groups of two bytes per characters had the bytes in wrong order.

Rather than 5eb63bbbe01eeed093cb22bb8f5acdc3

I saw something like e56bb3bb0ee1....

This was on Windows 7.

```
const string input = "hello world";

public static void Main(string[] args)
{

  using (System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
  {
    byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);

    byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

    // Convert the byte array to hexadecimal string
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
    {
      sb.Append(hashBytes[i].ToString("X2"));
    }
    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
  }
}
```

Java code is below for anyone interested.  As mentioned above, it only works to base 36.

```
private static final char[] BASE16_CHARS = "0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();
private static final BigInteger BIGINT_16 = BigInteger.valueOf(16);

private static final char[] BASE36_CHARS = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
private static final BigInteger BIGINT_36 = BigInteger.valueOf(36);

public static String toBaseX(byte[] bytes, BigInteger base, char[] chars)
{
    if (bytes == null) {
        return null;
    }

    final int bitsPerByte = 8;
    double bitsPerDigit = Math.log(chars.length) / Math.log(2);

    // Number of chars to encode specified bytes
    int size = (int) Math.ceil((bytes.length * bitsPerByte) / bitsPerDigit);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(size);

    for (BigInteger value = new BigInteger(bytes); !value.equals(BigInteger.ZERO);) {
        BigInteger[] quotientAndRemainder = value.divideAndRemainder(base);
        sb.insert(0, chars[Math.abs(quotientAndRemainder[1].intValue())]);
        value = quotientAndRemainder[0];
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```