# Adding hexa values in C#

Tags: c#

In my system,i need to add 2 Hexa values.So, how can i add hexa values in C#? And i also want to know the max length of Hexa values and which Instance hold these values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For 64 character numbers, you need to use the [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) type of .Net 4, the normal types are too small:

```
BigInteger bi1 = BigInteger.Parse("123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890abc5", NumberStyles.HexNumber);
BigInteger bi2 = BigInteger.Parse("123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890abc1", NumberStyles.HexNumber);
BigInteger sum = BigInteger.Add(bi1, bi2);
Console.WriteLine("{0:x}", sum); //or sum.ToString("x")
```

(remember adding a reference to `System.Numerics`)

Comment: But , i use .Net 3.5 version. I am sorry to ask again, how can i solve in .Net version 3.5

Comment: @Hset Hset Aung - In that case you need a library. Here are a few options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176775/big-integers-in-c

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers.Ok , i check at that link now.

Answer (score 16):

C# supports [hexadecimal literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674.aspx):

```
int i = 0xff;
```

However, they have the same numeric values as decimal literals - you are limited by the type you use. There isn't a special `Hexa` type.

If you have an integer and want to display is in hexadecimal base, you can use the `x` format ([example](http://ideone.com/kEPmr)):

```
int i = 255;
Console.Write(i.ToString("x")); // ff
Console.Write(i); // 255
```

Note that writing `i = 0xff` or `i = 255` is **exactly the same** - the value is resolved by the compiler, and you get the same compiled code.

Lastly, if you have strings with hexadecimal numbers, you can convert them to integers, sum them, and reformat them ([example](http://ideone.com/Ciqqe)):

```
string hexValue = "af";
int i = Convert.ToInt32(hexValue, 16); //175
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for your answer. But my Hexa value contains 64 characters so which instance can hold this when convert to some type?

Comment: @Hset Hset Aung - You should have mentioned you have such huge values `:)`. I've added another answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
  int a = 0x2;
  int b = 0x5f;
  int value = a + b; //adding hex values

  string maxHex = int.MaxValue.ToString("x"); //maximum range of hex value as int
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code for sum your result. You can see more on my [ByteConverters class](https://github.com/abbaye/WPFHexEditorControl/blob/master/WPFHexaEditor.Control/Core/Bytes/ByteConverters.cs)

```
    public static long HexLiteralToLong(string hex)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hex)) throw new ArgumentException("hex");

        int i = hex.Length > 1 && hex[0] == '0' && (hex[1] == 'x' || hex[1] == 'X') ? 2 : 0;
        long value = 0;

        while (i < hex.Length)
        {
            int x = hex[i++];

            if
                (x >= '0' && x <= '9') x = x - '0';
            else if
                (x >= 'A' && x <= 'F') x = (x - 'A') + 10;
            else if
                (x >= 'a' && x <= 'f') x = (x - 'a') + 10;
            else
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("hex");

            value = 16 * value + x;
        }

        return value;
    }
```

Usage :

```
var HexSum = HexLiteralToLong("FF") + HexLiteralToLong("FF");
```

Result :

```
510
```

Answer (score 1):

Hexadecimal values are just plain old integers (after all, the number 10 in base ten and the number A in hexadecimal are the same thing, just viewed differently); if you need to convert one to a hex string, use: `value.ToString("X")`, where `value` is an integral type (like `int`).

Answer (score 0):

On your last question: you can use hexadecimal constants in integer types (byte, short, int and long). In C# long is 64 bit, so longest hexadecimal constant is 0x1234567812345678 (or any other with 16 hexadecimal digits).

Comment: Well, not really *any* value with 16 digits, they aren't all equal, and half of them are too big - the maximal value for long is `0x7fffffffffffffff`: http://ideone.com/tdpIX , which is also visible in the specifications: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.maxvalue.aspx

Comment: Oh, I get it. You're talking about maximal *length*, not value.