# Adding Hexadecimal values to get a resultant hexadecimal

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, hex

I want to add two hexadecimals values to get a resultant hexadecimal value i have written the following code however when i print the value of resultant the resultant value is write for example `"abc" ->61+62+63=186` however on writing `jk ->6a+6b` i should get something like `d5` however it gives `12`.

this is tthe code i write:

i have also defined the globals as

```
  char buffer[20];
  long int li ;

  for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
      itoa(TextAlia[i], buffer, 16);
      li = li + atol (buffer);
  }
```

Comment: The representations `6a` (hexadecimal) `152` (octal),  `1101010` (binary) and `106` (decimal) are just notations that need their proper context for operations. Normally, standard math functions only work on **decimal** representations, so you'll need to convert your **number representation** into decimal (and back).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
li = li + atol (buffer);
```

`atol` stops at the first non-digit (decimal). To parse hexadecimal representations, use

```
li += strtol(buffer, NULL, 16);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume here that you have two strings "TextAlia" and "TextAlib," each of which contain a string representation of a hexidecimal number. One typical way to add the numbers and produce a hexidecimal string as output:

```
int a, b;
sscanf(TextAlia, "%x", &a);
sscanf(TextAlib, "%x", &b);
printf("%x", a + b);
```

This however is not the fastest possible way to add hexadecimal numbers in C, and is not written in typical C++ style either.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this: [Adding hexa values in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457712/adding-hexa-values-in-c-sharp)

Or try this:

```
int value = Convert.ToInt32(hexString1, 16) + Convert.ToInt32(hexString2, 16);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You probably confused `C++` with `C#`?