# Is there support for arbitrary precision arithmetic in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, math, bignum, arbitrary-precision

Does C# support arbitrary precision arithmetic (I think this is also called bignums)?

If it doesn't, which libraries do support it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176775/big-integers-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a `BigInteger` structure that supports arbitrary-size integers.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx

Nothing for floating-point though.

Comment: BigInt doesn't support arbitrary precision, it supports arbitrarily large integers. It only supports integers. If you want arbitrary precision, you need the BigNum class.

Answer (score 6):

You've already found the big integer; if you need big rational numbers (that is, fractions where the numerator and denominator are big integers) you can use the Rational class from the Solver library:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.solverfoundation.common.rational(v=vs.93).aspx

Answer (score 3):

F# has a BigNum type at `Microsoft.FSharp.Math.BigNum`, you should be able to use it from C# as well.

This type exists in the [F# Powerpack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/) . Download it and reference the appropriate DLL (I suppose it's FSharp.Powerpack.Dll, but you'll need a little trial and error).

Comment: fsharp sidnt show up in intellisense so i put csharp instead and it doesnt have Microsoft.CSharp.Math.BigNum, and as i said Microsoft.FSharp... doesnt exist either

Comment: ah thanks, i added the reference and now i can use Microsoft.FSharp exists, but not Mi..ft.FSharp.Math.BigNum?

Comment: That just goes to show you I shouldn't be handing out F# advice, having only started to use it today... It's part of the F# Powerpack. Hold on, I'll edit *again*.

Comment: thanks but i just found it under System.Numerics while looking through intellisense