# Applying bitwise or operator to decimal in c#

Tags: c#, decimal, bit-manipulation

In this code, I have a requirement like below:

```
decimal col;

if (condition)
{
    (decimal)col = (decimal)col | ((decimal)System.Math.Pow(2, 0)); 
}
```

When this code is compiled, I get an error saying

```
Operator | cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'decimal'
```

Can anyone explain, please? Thanks

Comment: What actually do you want? if using bitwise operator you have to use some integer-based type

Answer (score 8):

### Big numbers

As the compile-time-error says, you cannot use `|` on `decimal`. The `decimal` type is for numbers like `12.34`. If you're only using numbers like `12` or `34` then you may be better off using `int` (between ±2 billion) or `long` (between ±9 quintillion) depending how big your integer is.

Any number raised to the power zero, *n<sup>0</sup>* equals `1` so your `Math.Pow(2, 0)` can be replaced by `1`.

Your code could then look like this, which will compile.

```
int col;
```

and

```
if (condition)
    col = col | 1;
```

Finally, you *may* prefer to use the ternary operator `?:` to in-line your `if` statement, do whichever is more readable in your situation:

```
col = condition ? (col | 1) : col;
```

---

### Really big numbers

#### Using .Net 4.0 or above

If you need to use ***REALLY BIG*** integers, there is a class for that! [`System.Numerics.BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) (in `System.Numerics.dll`).

> The BigInteger type is an immutable type that represents an arbitrarily large integer whose value in theory has no upper or lower bounds.

Your declaration would then become:

```
BigInteger col;
```

And your bitwise operations as normal.

#### Using .Net 2.0 or above

Check out the project [IntX](http://intx.codeplex.com/)

> IntX is an arbitrary precision integers library written in pure C# 2.0 with fast - about O(N * log N) - multiplication/division algorithms implementation. It provides all the basic arithmetic operations on integers, comparing, bitwise shifting etc.

<sub>Reference: [Big integers in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176775/big-integers-in-c-sharp)</sub>

Comment: Forgot to mention that this code runs in a loop; so 0 in Math.Pow(2, 0) will become 1 in next iteration and so on... Also, for my requirement, I need to handle very big numbers, and nothing less than decimal will do...

Comment: If you're going to be using huge numbers, decimal is actually a poor choice. It's got a smaller range and higher precision than double. If you gave some more information on actual values we could be more helpful. Are you even going to be using decimal values, or are these just very large integers?

Comment: I (have to) use .NET 2.0 :(.. Also, this code is something which will run inside an SSIS package (SQL Server 2008)... so not sure if I can use fancy, latest namespaces / types

Comment: @NetTechie Edited with a .Net 2.0 option. Are you sure your number are going to be larger than `9,223,372,036,854,775,807` (`long.MaxValue`) though?

Answer (score -1):

Cast it to `Int64` then apply `|` operator.

```
decimal d1 = ..;
decimal d2 = ..;

var res = (long)d1 | (long)d2;
```

Comment: Am afraid this will result in truncation, because we have some huge values populated for LHS

Comment: Am not sure whether you can apply biwise operator with decimal type. So I suggested to ignore the fractional part.