# .NET Framework Library for arbitrary digit precision

Tags: .net, precision

I'm reviving this question, and making it more specific: Is there a .NET framework library that supports numbers with arbitrary digits of precision?

Comment: What you're looking for is an "arbitrary precision" decimal library, or maybe "bignum" type library. I haven't personally used any such libraries with .net, but maybe this question can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621684/arbitrary-precision-decimals-in-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few options here.

A good option is [W3b.Sine](http://www.codeplex.com/Wikipage?ProjectName=sine), which is native C#/.NET, and supports arbitrary precision floating point values.

If you are only dealing with integer values, [IntX](http://www.codeplex.com/Wikipage?ProjectName=IntX) provides support for arbitrary precision integer values.  A potentially more mature option would be [C# BigInt](http://www.emilstefanov.net/Projects/GnuMpDotNet/), but again, this will not support floating point operations.

Answer (score 6):

Can you wait for .NET 4.0? They're [bringing BigInteger directly into the Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2008/11/04/what-s-new-in-the-bcl-in-net-4-0-justin-van-patten.aspx).

On the other hand, if you can't wait, then the [J# runtime includes built-in support for java.math.BigInteger and BigDecimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163696.aspx). This is redistributable just like the rest of the .NET Framework.

Comment: Here are some BigInteger options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25375/how-can-i-represent-a-very-large-integer-in-net/98678#98678

Comment: Unfortunately these are arbitrary size integers not arbitrary precision natural numbers.

Comment: In this case look at these: J# library's java.math.BigDecimal

Answer (score 3):

You could try the old method of mantissa.  Basically you could have an 64 bit integer for storing the number and then a 64 bit integer for storing the exponent (which could be negative).  You could build your own object type and overload the arithmetic operators, so it will be treated as a single number.  It will require some work, but I think it will be your best option.

Comment: Theoretically this would be easy to do; value types are, under the hood, all simple structs anyway.

Comment: Never heard of Decimal data type? This solution needs a huge amount of work to be done...

Comment: Did you see the questioner comment about "i am planning on storing something in the way of billions of digits"?

Comment: You could start with this (which is the opposite of what you want, but it will give you an idea):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389993/extracting-mantissa-and-exponent-from-double-in-c

Here is some theory of the concept : 
http://www.cs.utah.edu/~zachary/isp/applets/FP/FP.html

Before floating points units were available on hardware this was how it was done.

Comment: @RCIX: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 3):

GnuMpDotNet: http://www.emilstefanov.net/Projects/GnuMpDotNet/

If you need pure .NET consider looking into this: http://www.codeplex.com/IntX/

Comment: Both of these cover arbitrary size integer classes, but do they offer abitrary precision natural numbers?

Comment: Natural number is a non-negative integer. So, they do.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase that. an arbitrary precision *decimal* number?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps surprisingly, the [Bailey-Borwein-Plouffe formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula) gives an incremental procedure for computing the next binary or hexadecimal digit of pi without needing to store all the previous digits.

Comment: It was back when the question asked how to calculate arbitrarily many digits of pi in C#, the questioner changed it a few months later to something "more specific" but in fact only tangentially related.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a really fast library then try:

http://www.emilstefanov.net/Projects/GnuMpDotNet/

Answer (score 1):

You can use decimal type which gives you 28-29 significant digits

Comment: that helps a little... but i am planning on storing something in the way of billions of digits. I was thinking something along the lines of a string solution but have no clue where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good article on how to represent infinite digits.

http://dobbscodetalk.com/index.php?option=com_myblog&show=Basic-Arithmetic-with-Infinite-Integers.html&Itemid=29

good luck