# Calculate PI using sum of inverse squares

Tags: c#, math, pi

I need to calculate PI with predefined precision using this formula:

[image]

So I ended up with this solution.

```
private static double CalculatePIWithPrecision(int presicion)
{
    if (presicion == 0)
    {
        return PI_ZERO_PRECISION;
    }

    double sum = 0;

    double numberOfSumElements = Math.Pow(10, presicion + 2);

    for (double i = 1; i < numberOfSumElements; i++)
    {
        sum += 1 / (i * i);
    }

    double pi = Math.Sqrt(sum * 6);
    return pi;
}
```

So this works correct, but I faced the problem with efficiency. It's very slow with precision values 8 and higher.

Is there a better (and faster!) way to calculate PI using that formula?

Comment: Is it really so slow as to be problematic if only executed once?

Comment: Try using `int` in `for` sentence. I suspect using double slows you down considerably there.

Comment: @ScottHunter Yes, it's slow. Look at numberOfSumElements variable and how it depends on precision.

Comment: @GrantWinney I have to :(

Comment: @Sopuli's suggestion of an `int` loop variable is good as long as `presicion` doesn't go above 8 (otherwise the `Pow(10, presicion + 2)` would overflow the `int`). You'd also need to change the `1` to `1.0` on the `sum +=` line to get the right results, and change `numberOfSumElements` to an `int` (with appropriate cast on the assignment) to get the most benefit.

Comment: the concept of calculating of `PI` is slow, why you don't calculate one time this, and save it for next time?

Comment: This wouldn't be faster, but you would get *better* (more precise) results if you flipped the direction of your loop, and summed the smaller terms first. A `double` can only hold 15-16 digits after the (floating) decimal point, so if you take something on the order of 1, and add something on the order of 1.23456789E-15, you lose everything but the 1.2 (or maybe just the 1) from the small number, because the 1 can only hold 15-16 digits after the decimal point. If you start with small numbers, you don't lose precision until the end when it's not important.

Comment: Also, you realize your loop is doing `numberOfSumElements - 1` iterations, right? (`for (double i = 1; i < numberOfSumElements; i++)`) So either your loop comparison should be `<=` instead of `<`, or your variable is misnamed.

Comment: Read the formula and code everyone. OP complains that loop is slow when *precision* >= 8, for which the loop is being run 10^10 times! That's 10,000,000,000 iterations. Of course that runs slowly.

Comment: If you have some leeway in choice of algorithm, check this posting:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283270/how-to-determine-whether-my-calculation-of-pi-is-accurate?rq=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
   double numberOfSumElements = Math.Pow(10, presicion + 2);
```

I'm going to talk about this strictly in practical software engineering terms, avoiding getting lost in the formal math.  Just practical tips that any software engineer should know.

First observe the complexity of your code.  How long it takes to execute is strictly determined by this expression.  You've written an *exponential* algorithm, the value you calculate very rapidly goes up as *presicion* increases.  You quote the uncomfortable number, 8 produces 10^10 or a loop that makes *ten billion* calculations.  Yes, you notice this, that's when computers starts to take seconds to produce a result, no matter how fast they are.

Exponential algorithms are *bad*, they perform very poorly.  You can only do worse with one that has *factorial* complexity, O(n!), that goes up even faster.  Otherwise the complexity of many real-world problems.

Now, is that expression actually accurate?  You can do this with an "elbow test", using a practical back-of-the-envelope example.  Let's pick a precision of 5 digits as a target and write it out:

```
 1.0000 + 0.2500 + 0.1111 + 0.0625 + 0.0400 + 0.0278 + ...  = 1.6433
```

You can tell that the additions rapidly get smaller, it *converges* quickly.  You can reason out that, once the next number you add gets small enough then it does very little to make the result more accurate.  Let's say that when the next number is less than 0.00001 then it's time to stop trying to improve the result.

So you'll stop at 1 / (n * n) = 0.00001 => n * n = 100000 => n = sqrt(100000) => n ~= 316

Your expression says to stop at 10^(5+2) = 10,000,000

You can tell that you are *way* off, looping entirely too often and not improving the accuracy of the result with the last 9.999 million iterations.

---

Time to talk about the real problem, too bad that you didn't explain how you got to such a drastically wrong algorithm.  But surely you discovered when testing your code that it just was not very good at calculating a more precise value for pi.  So you figured that by iterating more often, you'd get a better result.

Do note that in this elbow-test, it is also very important that you are able to calculate the additions with sufficient precision.  I intentionally rounded the numbers, as though it was calculated on a machine capable of performing additions with 5 digits of precision.  Whatever you do, the result can never be *more* precise than 5 digits.

You are using the *double* type in your code.  Directly supported by the processor, it does not have infinite precision.  The one and only rule you ever need to keep in mind is that calculations with *double* are never more precise than 15 digits.  Also memorize the rule for *float*, it is never more precise than 7 digits.

So no matter what value you pass for *presicion*, the result can **never** be more precise than 15 digits.  That is not useful at all, you already have the value of pi accurate to 15 digits.  It is Math.Pi

The one thing you need to do to fix this is using a type that has more precision than *double*.  In fact, it needs to be a type that has *arbitrary* precision, it needs to be at least as accurate as the *presicion* value you pass.  Such a type does not exist in the .NET framework.  Finding a library that can provide you with one is a [common question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169673/net-framework-library-for-arbitrary-digit-precision) at SO.