# Math .Net I want to represent a huuuuge number in .net

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I remember a class that formulate a huge number in array and do operations on it, What is it

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`System.Numerics.BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(VS.100).aspx).

Comment: Correct but I only have .Net 3.5, it is .Net 0.4

Comment: this is still being upvoted when the OP has stated that he is .net 3.5 only?  I suppose the class is there in 3.5, just internal so you could probably use it with some reflection hacks...

Comment: @Sam Holder: I had a look with Reflector, but wasn't able to find something like this in 3.5.

Comment: @Bobby: I was referring to something I read in one of the questions I linked to in my answer, I don't know that is the case from experience.

Comment: @Sam Holder: No offense there...I just wanted to say that I couldn't find something. ;) Though, now that you mention it, I can remember that there was/is such a class somewhere in the J# namespaces.

Comment: It is hidden in System.Core.dll, same namespace name.  You could copy it with Reflector.

Answer (score 6):

if you only have 3.5 then some external library should help.  there is [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/biginteger.aspx) which was linked from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279038/working-with-incredibly-large-numbers-in-net).  There are [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25375/how-can-i-represent-a-very-large-integer-in-net) which have [already addressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176775/big-integers-in-c) this too.  the search box is your friend :)